# hook_js_alter is getting cached

Tags: 8, caching

I recently come across a issue where my page was rendering two boostrap.js (Offcourse bad coding). An external Js from a module and another js from twitter bootstrap theme. Its causing some of the other js library to stop working(say **bootstrap.multiselect.js**).  So thought of removing the one of the js by mytheme_js_alter. Below code is working fine to achieve what is want, but with one execption. Sometime its does not work, and after clearing the cache it starts working.

```
function mytheme_js_alter(&$javascript, \Drupal\Core\Asset\AttachedAssetsInterface $assets) {
  $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
  $current_uri = \Drupal::request()->getRequestUri();
  if ($current_path == '/node/777' || $current_uri == '/mypage') {
    $external_bootstrap = 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js';
    if (array_key_exists($external_bootstrap, $javascript)) {
        $javascript[$external_bootstrap]['data'] = $javascript['https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js']['data'];
unset$javascript['https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.0/dist/js/bootstrap.js']);
    }
  }
}
```

Has anyone faced same issue of caching? Please suggest any solution to overcome this.

Comment: @MdEqbalAhmad, Did you got any solution, i have the same issue.

Comment: @WasimKhan I used libraries-override: instruction and mentioned path manually